# How Can I load null or empty collection in DevExpress Data Grid in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to add a collection to my data grid view but it seems like it needs data when it will be load.
I solve data entry in the grid after Load this grid but I can't load this data grid with empty collection. How can I do that? Here Is my code

[image]

From Here I sent a list to the grid.

[image]

```
optionsViewModels = await Task.Run(() => questionService.OptionsViewModels());
```

This line work properly. But `optionsViewModels = null;` cause error.

[image]

Here is my grid design. After collection doing Empty I faced this error 
[image]

Otherwise, it worked properly
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DxDataGrid` doesn't accept a `List` that is null but it does accept a `List` that is empty. Initialize your `List` like this:

```
var optionsViewModels = new List<OptionsViewModels>();
```

Or alternatively, only show the `DxDataGrid` when the `List` is not null:

```
        @if (optionsViewModels != null)
        {
            <DxDataGrid>

                ...

            </DxDataGrid>
        }
```

Comment: @SefatAnam Mark as answered?

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal , Done !